# AES 128 DOT NET and Java Compatibility

Tags: java, .net, cryptography, aes

We have been trying a prototype of a scheme where we encrypt decrypt data between two systems: One in .NET and the other in Java. We were going to use simple 128 bit AES Encryption.

The problem I am facing is trivial, but I cannot find a proper solution. Maybe my understanding of AES or Encryption in general is less.

Assuming we have a predefined key, represented by the following hex string: "9c361fec3ac1ebe7b540487c9c25e24e".
This is a 16-byte key.
The encryption part in Java would be

```
  final byte[] rawKey = hexStringToByteArray("9c361fec3ac1ebe7b540487c9c25e24e");
  final SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
  // Instantiate the cipher
  final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

  final byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
```

The 'hexStringToByteArray' function converts the hex string to a byte array. The problem is that in java, bytes are signed. So the value 9C is -100 and not 156 (as it would be in .NET).

In Java this becomes: `-100,54,31,-20,58,-63,-21,-25,-75,64,72,124,-100,37,-30,78`

In .NET however, this is: `156,54,31,236,58,193,235,231,181,64,72,124,156,37,226,78`

Question:
Given that the representation of the keys itself differs, would it affect the encryption process itself?
This is simple encryption without CBC and PADDING.

**Edit:** Updated the code to look formatted.

Comment: Hi I'm suffered by the same issue. My java encrypted data is different from the .net encrypt data. I followed the same method that you followed. need your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you've got a problem at all. You've got exactly the same data in both platforms. One version shows it as signed data, the other as unsigned... but the bits themselves are the same.

I wouldn't expect there to be any problem at all in using these keys for cryptography.

Comment: I actually had to do this across C#, Java, and Delphi.  As long as the encryption algorithm is the same, you should be good to to.

Comment: I realized that on my way back home after posting this question. Underlying bits should be the same! :)